# What do "dirty" and "uncommitted change" mean?

Tags: git

When saying a working tree directory is dirty or has uncommitted change, does it  mean that there is uncommitted change to some tracked file(s)? Does it include untracked files?

The same questions When saying the index is dirty or has uncommitted change.

Do being dirty or having uncommitted change mean the same? Does being dirty only applies to the working tree directory but not to the index? Does uncommitted change apply to both the working tree directory and the index?

For example, "You can only `git stash pop` into a clean working directory." Does `git stash pop` require the index to be clean or has no uncommitted change? What about `git push` and other git commands which updates the working directory and/or the index?

Thanks.

Comment: The "clean" vs "dirty" distinction is a loose (but useful) way to refer to whether there is unsaved work. Because there are *three* copies of every file—one in `HEAD`, one in the index, and one in the work-tree—there are two places that can be "dirty". (The `HEAD` commit copy cannot be "dirty", as it is 100% read-only and is as permanent as the commit itself.) Note that the claim *you can only `git stash pop` into a clean working directory* is false. It's a *good idea* to make sure the work-tree is clean first, but it's not *required*.

Comment: @torek Thanks. (1) Does "uncommitted change" mean exactly dirty working tree and/or dirty index? (2)  when  can I `git stash pop` into a dirty working directory? when  can I `git stash pop` into a dirty index? (3) Does the same thing for `git stash pop` apply to `git push`? (4) Does every git command require clean working tree, and/or clean index? What kinds of git commands require cleanness in working tree, and what kinds of git commands require cleanness in index, and what don't either?

Comment: Let me just address (1) here. When using the word "dirty", *nothing* means **exactly** anything, which is why I said "loose". I also did not use the phrase "unsaved changes" but rather "unsaved work", because no file, taken on its own, ever has *changes*. What, for instance, is the difference between README.txt? What other word(s) are you waiting for, before you can answer that question? The others need more room than there is in a comment. I'm not sure I have time to write up a good answer yet, but maybe I can start a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I may have to come back and edit this later to address the many (there are very many!) specifics of `git stash`, but let me start with an answer to this part:

> When saying a working tree directory is dirty or has uncommitted change, does it mean that there is uncommitted change to some tracked file(s)? Does it include untracked files?

As I put it in a comment, the word *dirty* is deliberately imprecise, so that we can communicate a general idea—that there's something you haven't saved somewhere—*without* being specific about the what, where, how, and so on.  The phrase *uncommitted change* or *uncommitted changes* is more precise, but is still missing something.  Let's take a concrete example, such as a file named `README.txt`:

```
$ cat README.txt
I am a readme file
with two lines of text
$
```

What are the *changes* in this file?  How could anyone ever answer this question?  That's like saying: *The high today is forecast to be 60, so how much warmer or colder is that?*  Well, OK, before we can say how much warmer/colder 60 is, we have to know: *Warmer or colder than what?*

#### State vs change

To see how much warmer or colder 60 is, we need to know what temperature we're supposed to *compare!*  Suppose the question is, instead, *The high today is forecast to be 60.  It was 60 yesterday and 55 a week ago.  How much warmer or colder is it going to be today than it was yesterday, and how much warmer or colder is it going to be today than it was last week?*  Now we have a *proper* question, and we can say *No different than yesterday, but 5 warmer than last week.*

If we have a *state* ("it's 60 outside" or "`README.txt` has these lines in it") and we want a *change* ("it's warmer/colder than last week" or "the second line used to say *some* text and now says *two lines of* text", for instance), we must also have the *previous* state, so that we can subtract.  If subtracting yesterday's, or last week's, state from today's gives zero, there is no change.  Otherwise, whatever the change is, that's the change.

#### Git keeps state, not changes

Git is, in general—there are specific exceptions to this rule that we won't get to here—quite state-oriented, and commit-centric.  For an example of the latter, a branch name just holds one commit hash ID.  The same is true of a tag name.  The key difference between these two is that a tag name identifies one particular commit for all time—or at least, it's designed to do so; tags should never move—while a branch name identifies the *last* commit that we should consider to be part of the branch.

Each commit, identified by its own unique hash ID, holds some metadata: who made it (name and email address) and when; their log message about *why* they made it; the hash ID of a *parent* commit; and a complete set of files, frozen for all time—well, for as long as the commit itself exists—and compressed into a special Git-only format.  As long as the commit itself continues to exist, you can always get all of those files back, in that form.

The compressed-and-read-only form is fine for *storage* but useless for getting any work done, so Git has to be able to take the files out of the deep-freeze, thaw them out, de-compress them, and turn them into useful—and writable—ordinary files.  These ordinary files go into your *work-tree* (or working tree or several variations on this phrase).  Here, you can use / work-on them.  To do so, you tell Git: *Get me the commit with hash ID H*, and *H* is now your current commit and you have the files from *H* to work on.  Typically you do this with, e.g., `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop`, and you get the files from the *latest* commit, whose hash ID is stored in the branch.

Because you *can* change the files in the work-tree, they can become different from those frozen into the current commit.  So we can compare the work-tree copy of a file like `README.txt` to the frozen (and Git-ified—Git just has to expand it out again internally) copy.  Subtracting the frozen version from the work-tree version shows us / Git what changed, if anything.

Most version control systems stop here, with two copies of each file: the frozen one in the commit, and the regular one in the work-tree.  Git, however, inserts a *third* copy, in between these two.  That third copy goes into what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*, depending on who / which part of Git is doing the calling.

This third copy is a complete copy of each file, just as before.  It's stored in the special Git-ified format.  The key difference between a committed copy and the index copy, though, is that the index copy isn't totally frozen.<sup>1</sup>  It's more *ready to freeze,* or sort of slushy.  To replace the index copy of some file named *`file`*, you run `git add file`.  That Git-ifies whatever is in *`file`* and stuffs the result into the index, ready to go into the *next commit you will make*.

In the end, this means that when you have a current commit, you have *three* copies of every file.  Git lets you name all three:

- `HEAD:README.txt` is the frozen, Git-only, committed copy.  Nothing can change it, so it's never "dirty", even if it's different from something we could compare it to.
- `:README.txt` is the index copy—still Git-only and mostly frozen, ready to go into the *next* commit, but it can be replaced at any time.  We can compare it to either the `HEAD` copy *or* to the work-tree copy.  It can be different from either one, and in either case, we can call *something* "dirty".  By comparing `:README.txt` to, say, `HEAD:README.txt`, we can tell whether *those two* are specifically different, or not.
- Last, `README.txt` is an ordinary file.  We can compare *it* to either the `HEAD` copy or to the index copy, but as far as Git knows, it can be replaced (or changed in place) by anyone or anything at any time.<sup>2</sup>  We can loosely say that it's "dirty" if it's different from *either* `HEAD:README.txt` or `:README.txt`, and get specific by comparing it to one or the other.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically it's just a *blob object*, with a Git hash ID, which means it really *is* frozen.  However, you can replace it any time with a new frozen copy.  If you never get around to committing one of these index copies, it may—as long as the content itself is different from any previously- or futurely-saved content—become an *unreferenced object* that Git will eventually *garbage collect*—but that's a bunch of terminology that you don't need to know.  For using Git, it suffices to think of the index copy as replaceable—because it is—without worrying about the exact details of this replacement process.

<sup>2</sup>Your operating system may allow you, or require you, to place restrictions on who can modify it, when, and how, but that's all outside the purview of Git itself.

---

#### Defining *tracked* vs *untracked*

Git often talks about *untracked files*, and again, for precision, we need a proper definition.  A file is *tracked* if and only if it is *in the index right now*.

You can put new files into the index: `git add newfile` copies `newfile` from the work-tree into the index, and if there *wasn't* a `:newfile` before, there is now.  You can also take files *out* of the index: `git rm newfile` removes `newfile` while also removing `:newfile`.

If you run `git commit` *right now*, Git will package up whatever is in the index *right now* and make that into the frozen files in the commit.  That is, the index has all the files, all Git-ified and slushy and ready-to-freeze, which is what makes `git commit` so fast: It just freezes the index copies into the new commit.  So the *tracked* files are the files that are in the index.

A file that's in a commit is there as long as the commit is there, because commits are frozen.  Files in the index are only there as long as they are in the index.  Moving from one commit to another, as in going from `git checkout master` to `git checkout branch`, will add files *to* the index, take files *out* of the index, and *replace* files in the index, when / if / as necessary to make that the current commit.  This also copies the files to your work-tree, or removes them from your work-tree, so that your work-tree has the (unfrozen and un-Git-ified) files for you to use.

But you can, at any time, create your own files in your work-tree and *not* add them to the index.  Whenever you do that, you have an untracked file.  Git generally does as little as possible with untracked files, except to constantly complain at you that they are untracked.

#### Finally, we can address the highlighted question

Let's put it here again:

> When saying a working tree directory is dirty or has uncommitted change, does it mean that there is uncommitted change to some tracked file(s)? Does it include untracked files?

When *making a new stash*, the `git stash` command mostly doesn't complain about, and mostly doesn't deal with, untracked files, except when using `--include-untracked` or `--all`.  So, with normal (no-extra-flags) use of `git stash save` or `git stash push`, the state of any untracked files is irrelevant.  It's hard to say whether such files are themselves "clean" or "dirty" as there's nothing obvious to compare them to in the first place.

So, for this case, we mostly need to concern ourselves with *tracked* files—files that are in the index.  There's an edge case here though that we should look at first.  Suppose that the current commit has a file named `yuck`, and we run:

```
git rm yuck
```

The file `yuck` is now *gone* from the index and work-tree.  The file `yuck` doesn't even exist.  (Is it untracked?  That's a good philosophical question; what about the file `asdf` that never existed, never went into any commit, and is not in the index and work-tree, is that untracked too?  Git has a nice concrete answer though: as long as it doesn't exist in the work-tree either, it's not an *untracked file*.)

If we run a comparison of `HEAD` vs index, though, we'll see that there's a *deleted file*.  The `git status` command runs that comparison for us, and tells us that there's a deletion ready to be committed.  So—here's our loose *dirty* word again—in this case, we will call the index dirty, because it's different from the `HEAD` commit.

So this gets us our first bottom line: if we run a comparison of `HEAD` vs the index, we'll also see any other files that are different.  If anything is different, the index—which is not yet a commit—definitely has *uncommitted changes*.  We'll also, loosely, call that dirty.

Similarly, this gets us our second bottom line: we'll run a second comparison, of the index vs the work-tree, while paying no attention at all to all the untracked files—all the files in the work-tree that *aren't* in the index.  The `git status` command does this second comparison, too, and lists out all the files that are different here.  If any files are different, the work-tree has *uncommitted changes*, and we will call it dirty.

Note that `git stash` itself uses the two separate comparisons: `HEAD`-vs-index, and index-vs-work-tree.  These are the *same* two separate comparisons that `git status` runs.  They tell us all we need to know for most purposes.  Some people—but not `git stash`—like to run a third comparison, `HEAD`-vs-work-tree (ignoring files in the work-tree that aren't in `HEAD`), and call *that* dirty if any differ.  But you can prove that if that third comparison would show some difference, then at least one of the two comparisons that `git status` and `git stash` do will *also* show some difference.  (Try it as an exercise.)  So the two comparisons suffice, and are what `git stash` uses here.

Comment: Thanks. "you can prove that if that third comparison would show some difference, then at least one of the two comparisons that git status and git stash do will also show some difference."  On the reverse, if the two comparisons  that git status and git stash do both show some differences, that third comparison may or might not show some difference. So they are not equivalent. Why use the two comparisons, not only the third comparisons?

Comment: @Ethan: right: suppose HEAD-v-index says: change README by addling a new line at line N, and suppose index-v-worktree says change README by removing that same line. Then HEAD-v-worktree shows no difference. Since Git is going to make the next commit from the *index*, that matters "more" in some sense, so it's best to do the two comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the working directory having uncommitted changes.

You can use `git diff HEAD` or `git status` to interrogate what is currently going on in your working directory.

If you don't care about files that have not been committed previously use `git diff HEAD` otherwise I prefer `git status`.

I've run both commands on a clean directory. See below for the results.

```
C:\Dev\dogs-api>git status
On branch bugfix/lowercase
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/bugfix/lowercase'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\Dev\dogs-api>git diff HEAD

C:\Dev\dogs-api>
```

Now I'll do some work on my branch to fix a bug in my code regarding lowercase strings. I've added a file and modified another, but I haven't added the files to the stage yet.

```
C:\Dev\identity-dog-api>git status
On branch bugfix/lowercase
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/bugfix/lowercase'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/newUntrackedClass.java

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/Distribution.java


C:\Dev\identity-dog-api>git diff HEAD
diff --git a/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/Distribution.java b/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/Distribution.java
index 770cec4..f1e17a6 100644
--- a/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/Distribution.java
+++ b/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/Distribution.java
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ public class Distribution {

     @XmlElement(name = "XYS")
     public dogName getDogName() {
-        return dog;
+        return dogName; //newVarLine()
     }

     public void setDogName(String dogname) {
diff --git a/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/newUntrackedClass.java b/src/main/java/au/com/api/model/request/newUntrackedClass.java
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f21156d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/main/java/au/com/dog/api/model/request/newUntrackedClass.java
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+package au.com.dogs.api.model.request;
+
+public class newUntrackedClass {
+}

C:\Dev\identity-dog-api>
```

Now that I've made some changes I can run store these changes using `git stash`. After doing this I'll make some other changes and demonstrate that you can run these commands on a dirty working directory.

If there are conflicts you'll have to resolve these as you would if you had a conflict between two branches.

This looks like.

```
C:\Dev\identity-dog-api>git stash pop
Auto-merging src/test/java/au/com/api/service/TokenIssuerUnitTest.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/test/java/au/com/api/unittest.java
Auto-merging src/main/java/au/com/api/web/rest/validation/ValidationUtils.java
Auto-merging src/main/java/au/com/api/web/rest/TokenController.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main/java/au/com/api/web/rest/TokenController.java
Auto-merging src/main/java/au/com/api/service/TokenIssuer.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main/java/au/com/api/service/TokenIssuer.java
Auto-merging src/main/java/au/com/api/service/Service.java
```